# Format data output using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the  following function which pulls data from the  database :

```
public function get_dataset() {
        $dataset = "";
        $data_set = $this->operations_model->get_date();
        foreach ($data_set as $value) {
            $dataset .= '["' . $value['date'] . '","' . $value['revenue'] . '"],';
        }

        echo $dataset;
    }
```

And return data in the following format :

```
["2015-10-13 15:53:20","15000.00"],["2015-10-13 15:53:20","5800.00"],["2015-10-13 15:53:20","5800.00"],["2015-10-13 15:53:20","5800.00"],["2015-10-13 15:54:56","15000.00"],
```

I would like to format the above data to be in the  following format :

```
[[2015-10-13 15:53:20,15000.00],[2015-10-13 15:53:20,5800.00],[2015-10-13 15:53:20,5800.00],[2015-10-13 15:53:20,5800.00],[2015-10-13 15:54:56,15000.00]]
```

Comment: `$dataset = "[";` and after your `foreach` loop `$dataset."]"`

Comment: So, what is the problem? All you need is to remove quotes from your strings in `foreach` and wrap the resulting string with braces in the end - no algorithms or something else, just string formatting. For me it sounds like `I know how to output the result of 1+1, now help me to calculate 2+2`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function get_dataset() {
    $dataset = "[";
    $data_set = $this->operations_model->get_date();
    foreach ($data_set as $value) {
        $dataset .= '["' . $value['date'] . '","' . $value['revenue'] . '"],';
    }
    $dataset = substr($dataset, 0, -1);
    $dataset .= "]";

    echo $dataset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```html
public function get_dataset() {
        $dataset = "";
        $comma='';
        $data_set = $this->operations_model->get_date();
        foreach ($data_set as $value) {
            $dataset .= $comma.'[' . $value['date'] . ',' . $value['revenue'] . ']';
            $comma=',';
        }

        echo '['.$dataset.']';
    }
```